# WPF property declared in C# code instead of XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, inotifypropertychanged

For some particular reason I have declared a binding in C# code instead of declaring it in XAML as usual. The problem I am facing is that when I change only one property of the object, the INotifyPropertyChanged works properly and propagates the changes as expected, but when I change the entire object (the reference), it does not work as expected.

You can see it in this sample code, where I set one initial value of "111", which works well, then I change only one property value to "222" and also works as expected, but when I set a new object, then it does not work.

What should I change in the code so the thrid assignment also works and the Text property is set to "333" via binding?

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MySubClass _selectedItem;
    public MySubClass SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
        }
    }
    private MySubClass _selectedItemBefore;
    public MySubClass SelectedItemBefore
    {
        get => _selectedItemBefore;
        set
        {
            _selectedItemBefore = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItemBefore));
        }
    }
    private MySubClass _selectedItemAfter;
    public MySubClass SelectedItemAfter
    {
        get => _selectedItemAfter;
        set
        {
            _selectedItemAfter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItemAfter));
        }
    }


    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        SelectedItemBefore = new MySubClass
        {
            FirstProperty = "111"
        };
        SelectedItemAfter = new MySubClass
        {
            FirstProperty = "333"
        };
        SelectedItem = SelectedItemBefore;
        var firstPropertyBinding = new Binding("FirstProperty") { Source = SelectedItem, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBox, TextBox.TextProperty, firstPropertyBinding);
        Console.WriteLine($"Text here is: {textBox.Text}");
        // It's "111", so OK!!!

        SelectedItem.FirstProperty = "222";
        Console.WriteLine($"Text here is: {textBox.Text}");
        // It's "222", so OK!!!

        SelectedItem = SelectedItemAfter;
        Console.WriteLine($"Text here is: {textBox.Text}");
        // ¡¡¡FAIL!!!: expected "333" but it is "222" yet
        // (here SelectedItem.FirstProperty == "333")
    }
    

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion        
}

public class MySubClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _firstProperty;
    public string FirstProperty
    {
        get => _firstProperty;
        set
        {
            _firstProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FirstProperty));
        }
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed == null)
            return;

        changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion   
}
```

UPDATE:
I know that a TextBox should never go in the ViewModel, nor anything related to the View, please, don't dwell on that detail. This code is just for learning purposes and to understand how Bindings work, but for now, I don't fully understand it. I would appreciate explanations on how to modify the code so that it does display "333".

Comment: You have `Source = SelectedItem` before reassigning `SelectedItem = SelectedItemAfter`. What do you expect? The Binding should be `new Binding("SelectedItem.FirstProperty") { Source = this };`

Comment: And why is there a TextBox in a view model??

Comment: As a Rule-Of-Thumb: When having an UI type in the ViewModel you did something wrong regarding MVVM

Comment: The textBox is there because it is just an example. This code is no good code, I know, but just wondering why it does not work as I expected.

Comment: @Clemens at that point SelectedItem.FirstProperty == "333", so I expected that textBox.Text was also "333". Why is it not?

Comment: Binding.Source still has the old value. It does not magically take the new value of the SelectedItem property.

Comment: @Clemens, when setting FirstProperty to '222', it does update, why doesn't it work the same when changing the entire object? I understand it's not 'magically,' but I thought it was through INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: This works, you are right: `new Binding("SelectedItem.FirstProperty") { Source = this }`. Thank you (if you write it as an answer I will mark it)

Comment: Again for your understanding, when you assign `SelectedItem = SelectedItemAfter` the Source property of the Binding still references the object in `SelectedItemBefore`. There is no way that the Binding would be notified about changes in a different object than its Source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let’s take a look at the  data sources of `Binding`:

- `Source`: Direct static binding source reference, which cannot be modified after binding is applied.

  - you can set this in XAML by `{Reference name}` to set a named element reference in this XAML scope.
- `RelativeSource`: According to the element to which the binding is applied and the mode of this RelativeSource, obtain other object as binding source based on the relative position of the binding applied element.

  - If `RelativeSource` target changing will change the reference of this binding source.
- `ElementName`: Set the name of an use `x:Name` named element defined in current XAML and in same visual tree.

  - It works similar to `Source` and also static, but simpler.
- None of the above are set: Binding source is the object(Control) own DataContext property, DataContext can be inherited in visual tree or document flow.

  - If `DataContext` changing will change the reference of this binding source.

Setted `Binding.Source` property will set a static **reference of object** as a binding source on this `Binding`.
But looks you want `Binding` to the `MySubClass.FirstProperty` from `MainWindowViewModel.SelectedItem`, but you set the `SelectedItemBefore` static reference on this binding.
So that you cannot do anyting with `SelectedItemAfter`.

The right way is that you should binding to `MySubClass.FirstProperty` of this `MainWindowViewModel.SelectedItem`:

```
var firstPropertyBinding = new Binding("SelectedItem.FirstProperty") { Source = this };
// OR
// textBox.DataContext = this;
// var firstPropertyBinding = new Binding("SelectedItem.FirstProperty");
BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBox, TextBox.TextProperty, firstPropertyBinding);
```

If `SelectedItem` changed, it will notify this binding source is changed and binding engine will update this binging target value. `.FirstProperty` means find `FirstProperty` in the `SelectedItem` referecd object.

And if in the `Window` or `UserControl` context, it would be better to use `DataContext`.
For example in window:

```
//set window DataContext as MainWindowViewModel
this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
//set textbox DataContext bind to MainWindowViewModel.SelectedItem
//by inherited DataContext from parent control
BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBox, TextBox.DataContextProperty,
    new Binding("SelectedItem"));
//based on TextBox.DataContext
//this binding source is refereced by MainWindowViewModel.SelectedItem
//and it's dynamic
BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBox, TextBox.TextProperty,
    new Binding("FirstProperty"));
```

Comment: A great, detailed, and clear explanation. The problem was that I was overlooking the "static" nature of the "Source" parameter; I thought that if its value was changed, it would continue to update, similar to when changing the value of a bound property. Clear now!